# Problem with \rowcolor command in nicematrix package

Tags: luatex, rowcolor, nicematrix

I am having problems with the `\rowcolor` command in `nicematrix` package. Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
We define the product \(AB\) by 
%Example 1
\begin{equation}
    \begin{bNiceMatrix}
        \CodeBefore
        code-before=\rowcolor{blue}{4}
        \Body
        a_{11}&a_{12}&\cdots&a_{1n}\\
        a_{21}&a_{22}&\cdots&a_{2n}\\
        \vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
        a_{i1}&a_{i2}&\vdots&a_{in}\\
        \vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
        a_{m1}&a_{m2}&\cdots&a_{mn}
    \end{bNiceMatrix}
\end{equation}
%Example 2
$\begin{pNiceMatrix}[r,margin]
    \CodeBefore
    \chessboardcolors{red!15}{blue!15}
    \Body
    1 & -1 & 1 \\
    -1 & 1 & -1 \\
    1 & -1 & 1
\end{pNiceMatrix}$

%Example 3
$\begin{NiceArray}{lll}[hvlines]
    \CodeBefore
    code-before = \rowcolor{red!15}{1,3-5,8-}
    \Body
    a_1 & b_1 & c_1 \\
    a_2 & b_2 & c_2 \\
    a_3 & b_3 & c_3 \\
    a_4 & b_4 & c_4 \\
    a_5 & b_5 & c_5 \\
    a_6 & b_6 & c_6 \\
    a_7 & b_7 & c_7 \\
    a_8 & b_8 & c_8 \\
    a_9 & b_9 & c_9 \\
    a_{10} & b_{10} & c_{10} \\
    \end{NiceArray}$
\end{document}
```

First, I tried to compile the first example.  I had texlive2020.  It said the command `\CodeBefore` is unknown.  Then, I saw that nicematrix package date was July 15, 2021.  So, I updated my texlive to 2021.  The example compiles, but the output is not correct.

[image]

I tried some of the examples in the documentation in page 13.  The chessboard example gives the correct output. But the `NiceArray` example does not give the  correct output as seen in the figure. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first environement `{bNiceMatrix}`, you have written:

```
\CodeBefore
   code-before=\rowcolor{blue}{4}
\Body
```

You should write

```
\CodeBefore
   \rowcolor{blue}{4}
\Body
```

The construction `\CodeBefore` - `\Body` will put all its contents as value for the key `code-before`.

Comment: @Pantigny Thanks.  It worked. But the third example is a verbatim copy from page 13 of the user manual.  It seems to compile correctly there. But, it does not compile correctly in my MWE.  I am puzzled.

Comment: You are right. There is an error in the documentation (in English). I will do the correction and the code of that example will be correct in the next version of `nicematrix` (I'm the author of the package `nicematrix`).